# Is any normal space Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

Since the definition of a normal space is:

I know that:

$1-$A space $X$ is said to be normal if all singleton sets are closed and if for any two disjoint closed subsets $A, B\subseteq X$ there are open sets $U,V \subseteq X$ such that $$A \subseteq U, B \subseteq V, \textbf{ and } U \cap V = \emptyset.$$

$2-$ A space $X$ is a Hausdorff if for every pair of distinct points $a,b \in X,$ there are open sets  $U,V \subseteq X$ such that $$a \in U, b \in V, \textbf{ and } U \cap V = \emptyset.$$

> **My intuition is YES  any normal space Hausdorff space. Am I correct? If so, Is there a good way to write a justification for this ?**

Comment: Note that not all topologists use this definition of *normal*. For me a normal space is one in which disjoint closed sets are contained in disjoint open sets; singletons are not required to be closed (i.e., the space is not required to be $T_1$). What you’ve defined here is what I would call a $T_4$ space, one that is both normal and $T_1$. And it makes a difference here: by the definition that you’re using, every normal space is Hausdorff, but this is not true by the one that I use.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you so much for this clarification. This is my first time to know this.

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Comment: The "or" in the first definition is weird, I would have used "and": now a $T_1$ space is normal, logically. We need that *both* are singletons are closed *and* disjoint closed sets can be separated. So then all points can too be separated, so it implies Hausdorff.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sorry about that I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straightforward from the given definition (which should rather use '**and**' instead of 'or' connecting the two conditions):

Just take $A:=\{a\}$ and $B:=\{b\}$ for given distinct points $a,b$.

Comment: 'all singleton sets are closed' - is part of the definition up here.